# How to zoom to selected Feature in ArcMap using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap

By using the QueryFilter I am getting some features based on the query and I am placing that feature names in a listbox.
When the user selects a particular name in the listbox that feature has to be zoomed to in the map.

Below is my code:

```
IQueryFilter pQueryFilter = new QueryFilterClass();
            pQueryFilter.WhereClause = textBox1.Text + textBox2.Text;
            ICursor pCursor = pFeatureClass.Search(pQueryFilter, true) as ICursor;
            IRow pRow = pCursor.NextRow();
while (pRow != null)
            {
                    listBox2.Items.Add(pRow.get_Value(9).ToString());
                pRow = pCursor.NextRow();

            }
```

Here is what I tried:

```
IActiveView pActiveView = pMxDocument.ActiveView;
            IGeometry pGeometry = pFeature.Shape;
            IEnvelope pEnvelope = pGeometry.Envelope;

            pActiveView.Extent = pEnvelope.Expand(1.2, 1.2, true);
```

But I am unable to zoom.

Comment: so feature is not selected in the map.right?

Comment: Do you want to select the feature and highlight it or just zoom the map?

Comment: I want to zoom that feature which i selected in ListBox

Comment: @Jagadesh - please post where you are going wrong..

Comment: @Jagadesh I added some comment in my answer. may be you missed it. you need to pass false in the expand method's third argument and you have to refresh arcmap's active view. For experimental please use pEnvelope.Expand(10, 10, false);

Comment: @Jagadesh you made a mistake here. the Expand method returns nothing. you have to set pActiveView.Extent = pEnvelope

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not tested.

```
public void ZoomTo(IGeometry geometry)
{
    IMxDocument doc = (IMxDocument)ArcMap.Application.Document;
    IMap map = (IMap)doc.FocusMap;
    IActiveView pActiveView = (IActiveView)map;     
    IEnvelope pEnvelope;

    if (geometry is IPoint)
    {
          IEnvelope currentEnv = pActiveView.Extent;
          IPoint point = (IPoint)geometry;
          currentEnv.CenterAt(point);
          pActiveView.Extent = currentEnv;
          map.MapScale = 100; //to set the scale to 1:100         
    }
    else
    {
        pEnvelope = geometry.Envelope;
        pEnvelope.Expand(1.2, 1.2, true);

        pActiveView.Extent = pEnvelope;
    }

    pActiveView.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: Now i want to zoom to some collection of features where all are point features then how to work with it.

Comment: check http://snipplr.com/view/48443/

Comment: If the geometry coordinate system is geographic and geometry type isn't point, then pEnvelope.Expand(1.2, 1.2, true); will zoom to a very big extent.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following (assuming names are unique):

1. Store the feature reference returned by *pFeatureClass.Search(pQueryFilter, true).NextFeature()* in a hashtable (data structure is not important), with key=name & value=actual feature object
2. On the selection changed event for the list, call
   *pActiveView.Extent=(hashtable[SelectedListItem] as IFeature).Extent*
3. This should zoomt to the feature (but wont select it upon zooming)

Comment: I slightly changed my code instead of **ICursor** i have taken **IFeatureCursor** from that i am getting **IFeature** i tried but its not zooming to the feature

Comment: I saw that, any specific reason for it...do you intend to re-use it later?

Comment: if the Geometry is an IPoint, it may not zoom..you might have to apply a buffer i think..

Comment: You could store the feature reference directly in the ListView using its [ListViewItem.Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.tag%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) property. Just be sure to use a non-recycling cursor.

Comment: @vinayan yes it is point feature how to zoom now

Comment: The IHookActions method I suggested uses the following logic when a point is used: `When passing DoAction an object implementing IPoint and esriHookActionsZoom, if the width of the specified geometry is zero, the display will be zoomed to 1/20th of the width of the full extent of the data. If the height of the current visible extent is less than 1/20th of the height of the full extent of the data, the current visible extent is used instead.`

Comment: @Jagadesh - you are better off using blah's suggestion..other option would be create a new envelope,center it at the point location,set activeiew extent to your new envelope, in the case of a Point

Comment: @vinayan i tried but its not working fine

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the [`IHookActions`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IHookActions_Interface/0016000001q8000000/) interface for this, e.g.:

```
hookActions.DoAction(feature.Shape, esriHookActions.esriHookActionsZoom)
```

See also this sample: [Using HookActions in custom commands](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/000100000258000000.htm)

Comment: HookAction is the only method to zoom ? because i am beginner and not aware of hookactions

Comment: There are at least 3 ways to skin this cat... I am just offering one more.

Comment: This is only applicable to ArcEngine and no the Desktop

Comment: @FaridCher Are you sure? I remember testing it with ArcMap and it worked fine.

Comment: I haven't tested this with Desktop. But If you open IHookActions documentation (your own link), you will only see Arc Engine under Product Availability!

Comment: I don't pretend to understand ESRI's documentation, but the [sample](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/000100000258000000.htm) this is used in is deployable to ArcView, ArcEditor and ArcInfo, e.g. desktop licenses. If you are able to test it, please do so. I haven't worked with ArcObjects in a long time so I can't verify this myself.

Answer (score 1):

you just have to find out which feature the user selected.

**ADDITION:**
May be for point feature the extent is so small that map can not zoom that much. So you need to make an envelope of that point and expand it as much as the map needs.

For point features:

```
IGeometry pointGeo = selectedFeature.Shape;
IEnvelope envelope = pointGeo.Envelop;
envelope.Expand(10,10,false);
map.ActiveView.Extent = envelope;
map.ActiveView.Refresh();
```

see more fore [IEnvelope.Expand Method](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Expand_Method/002m0000018q000000/). This should work.

Comment: I want to zoom that feature in Map at minimum map scale

Comment: @Jagadesh what do you mean by "minimum map scale"? Also, no such requirement was not stated up front (a bit unfair).

Comment: For a particular Layer in a Map there are huge amount of Features placed. By querying particular fields i want to zoom that particular feature which user selected.

Comment: Okay... so you want to zoom to a feature. We got that part. What do you mean by "minimum map scale" is there a minimum scale level (e.g. 1:1200) that you don't want to automatically zoom below?

Comment: (e.g. 1:2) so that we can see only that feature

Comment: @Jagadesh what do you mean by at minimum map scale?

Comment: @Emi, There may be a language barrier here, but it sounds like this is a non-issue. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @Jagadesh if I got it right, after zooming the map you want to see only the selected feature. let me know is it what you want or not

Comment: @Emi yes that means maximum zoomin to that feature

Comment: As I know feature.Extent should do this. Is it a point feature, that user selects

Comment: @Emi yes it is point feature

Comment: I have edited my answer. have a look

Comment: As my point of view here the Expand method is the most important thing. So, try some values here

Comment: @Emi i tried but its not working nothing change in the Map view

Comment: May be after doing the operation you need to refresh the map's active view. I just tried it. it works for me

Comment: One more thing, you should set false the variable ratio

Comment: @Emi but other than point feature its working fine anyway now i got the solution tq Emi and Vinayan