# Displaying Images in an Image Coordinate System

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-10.4

I'm trying to programmatically do what's explained [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/displaying-images-in-an-image-coordinate-system.htm). ('Focus on Image' to display an image in the Image Coordinate System.

I'm using a mosaic Layer to load an oblique dataset. 
Currently I'm able to access a selected feature by getting the feature with:

```
ICompositeLayer compositeLayer = mosaicLayer as ICompositeLayer;
IFeatureLayer featureLayer = compositeLayer.Layer[1] as IFeatureLayer;

IFeatureSelection featureSelection = featureLayer as IFeatureSelection;
ISelectionSet2 selectionSet = featureSelection.SelectionSet as ISelectionSet2;

ICursor cursor = null;
selectionSet.Search(null, true, out cursor);

IFeatureCursor featureCursor = cursor as IFeatureCursor;
IFeature feature = featureCursor.NextFeature();
```

and zooming to it with the answer from [zoom to geometry](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46689/how-to-zoom-to-selected-feature-in-arcmap-using-arcobjects)

From here I would like to now view the selected feature's image in ICS.

This is currently only one aspect of what I'm trying to do with ArcObjects, which is make an add-in for Oblique display for Desktop.

Anything that would be helpful to first, display an image in ICS or to navigate an display Oblique Imagery using ArcObjects for ArcMap would be helpful

**Using a selected footprint of a mosaicLayer How can I display the associated image in the Image Coordinate System?**

Also, do I need to first load the raster from the selected footprint/FeatureLayer?

Comment: For help with code we need you to provide a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: By "Oblique" do you mean you have oblique images, or is Oblique a brand name for a tool you've used to create ortho images?  If the previous, then I would take a look at implementing `IPictureElement2` or look at doing a hyperlink assuming you have an external viewer you can launch via a uri, if the latter, then perhaps ask where the sdk is to develop wrappers for unsupported raster datatypes (I can't remember where that is documented).

Comment: I have oblique imagery. We currently have a Oblique Viewer widget for web. Think [this](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/create-apps/widget-oblique-viewer.htm) and [this](https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/api-reference/oblique-viewer.htm). We are working to have something similar using ArcMap for Desktop.

Comment: After "Focus on Image" it's setting the SpatialReference of the map to "AMD_'mosaicLayerName'_CAT\Raster.OBJECTID= 'oid'" I'm beginning to think that I will have to get the raster and then somehow set the map to use it as it's SpatialReference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using an Image service you can use IImageServer5's function "GetImageCoordinateSystem(int OID)"

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/IImageServer5_GetImageCoordinateSystem.htm

```
IMap map = ArcMap.Document.FocusMap;
IImageServer imageServer = GetImageServer(serviceUrl, serviceName);
IImageServer5 server5 = imageServer as IImageServer5;
map.SpatialReference = server5.GetImageCoordinateSystem(OID);
IMxDocument mxdoc = ArcMap.Application.Document as IMxDocument;
```

Comment: This does work for ImageServers. I guess ESRI doesn't have support for doing this with ArcObjects for Mosaic datasets. Now I just need to re-learn everything I just learned for mosaicLayers and learn it for ImageServers... I'll accept this answer just because I dont think there's any other way in ArcObjects. [without transforming it manually]